# How to give hard coded wait in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to force web driver to wait specified amount of time before it moves to the next step. I have used two types of wait implicit and thread. None is working. It just moves to the next step without waiting. How can I force driver to wait as specified before it moves to the next step?

```
package com.examplesite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.examplesite.base.BaseTest;
import com.examplesite.base.CsvDataProvider;
import com.examplesite.pages.HomePage;
import com.examplesite.pages.LogInPage;
import com.examplesite.pages.ProfilePage;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.testng.Assert;

public class LoginTest extends BaseTest{

@Test
public void cmetlogin() throws InterruptedException{
HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
homePage.launchURL();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1800, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
homePage.enterUSERNAME("aa42a");
Thread.sleep(20);
homePage.cmetPWfield("aaaa");
}
```

Comment: What are the units of the parameter of `sleep()`?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally it's not advisable to put hard coded wait in code. You may choose explicit or fluent wait based on specific element. I can help you out in this context if need any.

You may use below snip if still wanna go with hard coded wait:

```
//import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Sleeper;

Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER.sleep(new Duration(<<int wait>>, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Please community know if it works as you expected.

Thanks!